# Spring boot 1.4 - REST API Testing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

i wanted to write Test for my Spring mvc REST Controller. I am following official documentation from https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4 and so just updated version `to 1.4` and added spring boot as doc suggests.

I have added following dependencies :

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and the parent

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
```

My LoginController API which i want to test looks like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<HashMap<String, Object>> login() {


          // some logic to get Customer
        return new ResponseEntity<>(customer, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

And as per documentation here is my Test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(LoginController.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AuthorizationAndAuthenticationTest extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    private LoginController loginController;
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @MockBean
    private LoggingService loggingService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        given(this.loggingService.logInfoMessage("some Dummy Message", this.getClass())).
        this.restTemplate.getForObject("/login", Object.class);
    }
}
```

**Problems** :
1. Since login Controller is using many Services, i wanted to Mock them using **"given"**  but it gives compilation problem, seems like i am missing some dependency though not sure.
2.TestRestTemplate is deprecated and what is the alternative ? i did not find any alternative.

This is first time i will be writing Tests using Spring framework so it is possible i am overlooking some minute details.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning problem #1: You are probably forgot [to call `.withReturn`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.29/org/mockito/Mockito.html#bdd_mockito) while trying to stub `logInfoMessage`:

```
given(this.loggingService.logInfoMessage("some Dummy Message", this.getClass()))
   .willReturn("your desired value")
```

Concerning problem #2: [org.springframework.boot.test.TestRestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/TestRestTemplate.html) is deprecated in favor of [org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html).

So just change the package.

BTW, most suitable construct for testing Spring MVC endpoints is [MockMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) not TestRestTemplate.